# Why is this slash needed?

Tags: bash, awk

I created a `bash` script to thumbnail all images in a tree. It is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

find -path "thumbnails/" -prune -or -iname "*.jpg" -exec \
    bash -c 'convert "$0" -resize 256x256 thumbnails/`sha512sum "$0" | awk "{ print \\$1 }"`.jpg' {} \;
#                                                                                   ^^
```

In the awk command, there is a double `\\`. (I've marked it with `^^` on the commented line, but you'll probably need to scroll →) Why do I need two backslashes here? I need one to prevent the shell from attempting to expand `$1`, but otherwise, we are working within just a single set of single-quotes, which shouldn't be messing with the number of slashes. Yet, with just one backslash, `awk { print  }` gets executed, which isn't correct.

**Why the `\\`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I need two backslashes here? I need one to prevent the shell from attempting to expand $1, but otherwise, we are working within just a single set of single-quotes, which shouldn't be messing with the number of slashes.

There are actually two shells here which do all the usual variable/path substitions/expansions, one is

```
bash -c
```

the other is the backtick operator:

```
`command`
```

You need another backlash to prevent expanding of `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run

```
convert "$0" -resize 256x256 thumbnails/`sha512sum "$0" | awk "{ print \$1 }"`.jpg {}
```

through a `bash -c` for each file. So when you add the command as an argument of `bash`, you wrap it with single quote `''`. In which case you need to *escape* the backslash with one more backslash. That is

```
bash -c 'convert "$0" -resize 256x256 thumbnails/`sha512sum "$0" | awk "{ print \\$1 }"`.jpg ' {}
```

Answer (score -2):

A double backslash ensures that a single backslash will be part of what is printed, in other words if `$1` holds the value "xyz" the script will print `\xyz`

Comment: No, a double backslash is ensuring that the variable is printed: in neither the one or two backslash case is a backslash actually output. In the single backslash case, `$1` is evaluated by `bash` — this is unintended, and since it has no value, awk gets `{ print }`, which is wrong. In the two backslash case, awk gets `{ print $1 }` and `$1` is (as desired) evaluated by `awk`.